# Repeat a tuple inside a tuple

Tags: python, tuples

Is there a way to repeat a tuple inside a tuple ?

If I do something like

```
a = ((0, 1) * n)
```

I still get

```
a = (0, 1, 0, 1 ..... n times)
```

what if I want something like

```
a = ((0, 1), (0, 1) ... n times)
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Multiply a tuple with a tuple as its item. Don't forget a trailing `,`.

```
>>> ((0, 1),) * 5
((0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1))
```

Comment: Great solution. Works with lists too!. [(0,1),] * 5

Answer (score 1):

You might also be interested in a generator.

```
>>> def f():
...     for i in range(10):
...         yield (0, 1)
... 
>>> tuple(f())
((0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1))
```

Comment: `((0, 1) for i in xrange(10))` is the same generator.