# tuple or list of repeating tuples

Tags: python, tuples

Must be a very straight forward way of doing this - I have a tuple and I want to create a tuple of this tuple but with x number of repetitions, eg 4 below. Alternatively I can have a list of tuples and convert to tuple from there.

```
base_tuple = (0,1)
num_tuples = 4
```

output I want

```
((0,1),(0,1),(0,1),(0,1))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `*` operator to make repetitions of a tuple.

```
base_tuple = (0,1)
num_tuples = 4
result = (base_tuple,) * num_tuples
```

Comment: (which is the accepted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19753279/6045800)...)

Answer (score 1):

```py
>>> base_tuple = (0, 1)
>>> num_tuples = 4
>>> tuple([base_tuple] * num_tuples)
((0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
output = tuple(base_tuple for _ in range(4))
```